Inserting links and anchors directly with LuaLaTeX or the l3backend
Consider the following MWE (compile with LuaLaTeX) that inserts a target and a destination, without using hyperref, but using LuaTeX primitives and pdf mark up language.
My question has two parts:

How can I improve the LuaLaTeX part and,
How would the same example be written using the l3backend module.

Edit: As per Joseph's comment, please read l3pdf for l3backend.
    \documentclass{article}

    \begin{document}

    % Define the destination
    \pdfextension dest name {target1} xyz
    This is the destination (target), scroll to the next page for link.

    \newpage

    % Define the clickable anchor (jump link)
    Here is the anchor: \pdfextension startlink user {
      /Subtype /Link /A << /S /GoTo /D (target1) >>
    } Click here to jump to the target
    \pdfextension endlink.


    \ExplSyntaxOn
    \pdf_version:
    \ExplSyntaxOff
    \end{document}


With l3backend the answer is simple: you don't - l3backend is all private functions to support e.g. l3pdf

@JosephWright I should have tagged it l3pdf. How can I rewrite the example with l3pdf?

anchors (destinations) can be inserted with \pdf_destination.nn, see interface3. For support for links you must load the pdfmanagement by using \DocumentMetadata{}. The commands are described in l3pdfannot.pdf. In both cases the commands are not luatex specific. The main point of such abstracted commands is to be not engine  specific.

@UlrikeFischer  Thanks. Very useful information, especially the l3pdfannot.pdf.
